# how can i use MUI autoComplete onChange details in v4

Tags: material-ui, autocomplete

I want to know the currently selected value, so I would need the details parameter. However, it seems that mui v4 does not support this approach, at least I couldn't find it in the official documentation. Is there a way to use details in v4?

```
onChange: function(event: object, value: T | T[], reason: string) => void
```